# I created a website using Flask and there is two html pages how to connect them?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am new in flask and I would like to connect two pages of html the first one is called index which contains a dropdown list, the second on is called results which show the information as a pie chart
for every option in the index file I would like to assign a different URL such as if you chose week 1 the result file will show you how many mortalities have been from covid-19 in a pie chart

```
[this is the python file][1]
[this is the index.html][2]
[this is the results.html][3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the code to get the results:

```
@app.route("/whatever")
def whatever():
    return render_template("get_user_input_on_week.html")
```

Then in get_user_input_on_week.html:

```
<form action="/showdata">
<select name="week">
<option value="1">Week 1</option>
<option value="2">Week 2</option>
<option value="3">Week 3</option>
<option value="4">Week 4</option>
<!-- And so on -->
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Get Data!">
</form>
```

Then in your other app.route:

```py
@app.route("/showdata")
def showdata():
    week = int(request.args.get("week"))
    # code for getting data
    return render_template("data.html", data=data)
```

Then finally, in data.html:

```
<h1>Cases are {{data}}</h1>
```

If you want the page to not reload after selecting your week, learn about [AJAX](https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/Flask/Python_Flask_with_AJAX_JQuery.php).

Comment: Rather than writing all the option statement he can run a for loop which would be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use route and define a function like

```
@app.route("/",methods=["GET","POST"])
def index():
    var = "this is varible"
    return render_template("index.html",var1 = var)
```

then another route

```
@app.route("/result",methods=["GET","POST"])
def result():
    var2 = "this is another variable"
    return render_template("results.html",var2 = var2)
```

Comment: how to get the specific choice which the user selected such as week1 or week 2 and specify what every choice should have as url  and is there any changes I should in index.html file?

Comment: Where you are getting the pie chart data from. You can use slug like `app.route("/result/<sno>")` the pass the parameter `sno` to function `result(sno)`. Now in html where you are using dropdown list and use a for loop and give anchor tag with her like `href='/result/{{i}}'` where I can be numbers like 1 2 3 and then sno in results function will be equal to the number in url.